# Unspecified entity is shown during spring boot jpa transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Recently i'm facing weird issue while developing spring data jpa application.

I thought lazy fetched collection type entity is only fetched when it is actually accessed or when i fetch it with fetch join. But i can see unspecified entity which is not located in select clause nor from, where clause during debugging time.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Project extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final List<ProjectGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final List<ProjectMember> projectMembers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Builder
    public Project(
        String name
    ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addGroup(ProjectGroup group) {
        this.groups.add(group);
        group.setProject(this);
    }

    public void removeGroup(ProjectGroup group) {
        this.groups.remove(group);
        group.setProject(null);
    }

    public void addProjectMember(ProjectMember projectMember) {
        this.projectMembers.add(projectMember);
        projectMember.setProject(this);
    }

    public void removeProjectMember(ProjectMember projectMember) {
        this.projectMembers.remove(projectMember);
        projectMember.setProject(null);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "project_groups")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class ProjectGroup extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PROJECT_GROUP_PROJECT"))
    private Project project;

    @Builder
    public ProjectGroup(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "project_members")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class ProjectMember extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PROJECT_MEMBER_PROJECT"))
    private Project project;

    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String nickname;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    private boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Builder
    public ProjectMember(
        String nickname,
        boolean isDeleted
    ) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}
```

Those are my entities as you can see all the collection type entities are set as `FetchType.LAZY` which is the default value.

And this is my repository and service class

```java
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {

    @Query("""
        select distinct p
        from Project p
            left join fetch p.groups
        where p.id = :id
    """)
    Optional<Project> findWithProjectGroupsById(@Param("id") Long id);

}

@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProjectQueryServiceImpl implements ProjectQueryService {

    private final ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Override
    public ProjectResponseDto fetchWithMembersAndGroups(Long id) {
        return projectRepository.findWithProjectGroupsById(id)
            .map(ProjectResponseDto::new)
            .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }
}
```

The service code is very simple it only fetch project with group entity with fetch join. You can see clearly there is no member entity in this query.

And the generated query looks like this

```sql
    select
        distinct project0_.id as id1_2_0_,
        groups1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        project0_.created_at as created_2_2_0_,
        project0_.modified_at as modified3_2_0_,
        project0_.name as name4_2_0_,
        groups1_.created_at as created_2_0_1_,
        groups1_.modified_at as modified3_0_1_,
        groups1_.name as name4_0_1_,
        groups1_.project_id as project_5_0_1_,
        groups1_.project_id as project_5_0_0__,
        groups1_.id as id1_0_0__ 
    from
        projects project0_ 
    left outer join
        project_groups groups1_ 
            on project0_.id=groups1_.project_id 
    where
        project0_.id=?
```

But when i set the break point right after the above query is executed i can see the unspecified member entity
[image]

Does anyone know why this happens? I've tried to find out but still couldn't find any reason.

If you want to reproducible [sample code](https://github.com/Y-k-Y/jpatest/) please use it and you can easily reproduce it when you run the test method and set break point in the `PostResponseDto` so that you can pause test right after executing repository method.

Comment: The debugger uses the class itself to 'see' the data, which causes it to be fetched. Groups is being fetched joined in, which you can see in the executed query, while the projectGroups is being fetched separately because you are accessing it through the debugger. Turn on SQL logging and let it run without debugging - if you don't see the query on ProjectMember, it isn't being fetched

Comment: @Chris But i can't see any related entities in debugger using this query `select p from Project p`. If debugger fetches to see the data somehow then this query should fetch other entities as well

Comment: Check the logs - you should be able to determine when the query for ProjectMembers is issued. If it isn't issued, it isn't fetched. As for other queries - you should be able to see what is in the collection by expanding them. Have you maybe read in this Project instance before and had it fetch the projectMembers? You might be getting the cached instance from before. You need to see the query doing the fetch to figure out what is executing it - and it isn't in what you've shown us

Comment: The member entity is only shown in the transaction then it is disappeared after transaction is finished. Also i can’t see any logs related member entity so it is not actually fetched as you said but why other entities still remain as proxy. Showing as proxy is what unselected entities should be isn’t it? Like i see when using default `findById`

Comment: Are we debugging your debugger, or are you looking at debugging real world results in your application? I can only help guess at what you are seeing. If there is no query for the ProjectMembers occurring in your application at all - I could guess that maybe you have these Project instances and their ProjectMembers already cached from earlier application access. You'll have to figure out where/when they are fetched - maybe put a lock in the table and check to see if any threads are stuck blocked on it

Comment: It appears on both local dev environment and the sample code i linked. I need to dig it in more since there is no explicit log. Thank you for your help anyways.